# Drupal 7 adding bulk users to group or roles

Tags: drupal-7

Is there a way to bulk add users to roles or group in Drupal 7.

I want to add users based on Profile 2 field(s) on filters like (Gender=Male and Age>=18) and so on.

I need to do this in order for Drupal content to be accessible to a specific group(s) or role(s) only.

I went through some modules (http://drupal.org/project/content_access, http://drupal.org/project/simple_access) but I'm really confused, on what suits best.

Answer (score 2):

Try [User Import Framework](http://drupal.org/project/uif) which allows you to use a CSV file to create new users and assign roles